# Blackberry bar signing error

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-jde, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have an android application and want to port it to BB 10 device. I have converted it to bar file with command line tools and configured my computer for signing application. But when i am trying to sign application it gives error.

Command Line :

```
 batchbar-signer MyFile.bar author.p12 password
```

It gives error

```
blackberry.tools.SDK\lib/KeyTool.jar
Error: null
```

Also tried online tools to sign my application but online tools gives error,too

Installed blackberry plug-in for Eclipse as an alternative , also it doesnt work.

My ADT Version : 21.0.1
JRE Versiyon : 7u21
Blackberry SDK : 1.5.2

Waiting for your help

THANKS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe the reason currently for the error with signing the application is that you are using Java 7 version while BlackBerry current Java support is Java 6 - [spec docs](https://developer.blackberry.com/android/documentation/sys_requirements_1848536_11.html)

Does it continue giving you an error if you change to an earlier Java versions?